# Is it possible to open a file in shared mode without changing the file handler?

Tags: python, windows, fopen

In Python I open a temporary file for write by using [`tempfile.mkstemp`](http://docs.python.org/library/tempfile.html) in order to be sure that the file is destroyed when released (even if application crashes).

Now I need to pass this file to another application but this application is not going to be able to open the file as long the file is opened for write.

Can I change the access mode or reopen the file without changing the file handle in order to prevent it from being deleted too soon?

Update: opening the file in read mode does not solve the problem, the file must be opened in `shared` mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no documented way to switch the file modes (r, w, a) for an open file.

Instead of *TempFile*, consider using [mmap](http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/mmap/index.html#module-mmap) to share data between programs.

Comment: While this could be a nice alternative I don't want to add new modules.

Comment: Why not?  The *mmap* module is already in the standard library.  The only "cost" to using it is typing ``import mmap``.

Comment: Not in Python 2.5, and it's currently impossible to upgrade.

Answer (score -1):

Why not open it in `'a'` mode? That way you can read and append?

Also why not open the TempFile manually then at an atexit event to delete when your program is done.

Comment: You can read 'a' mode files though. So why not just pass the file object between the programs.